# Difference of Spring session management and spring security session?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am new with spring ,I have a doubt about **spring session management** and **spring security session** ,whether both concept are same or different ? If different what are that ? Any  suggestion ?

Comment: What "spring session management" are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

May you be a little bit more specific in your question?

In Spring:

- `session` can refer to one of the scopes that a bean belongs to. For example, if you define an instance (bean) of a class a `org.something.Counter` with scope `session`, whenever you will access that bean during a web session you will have the same instance of the object. Web session does not require Spring Security in order to exists. You can start from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-other) to understand a little bit more about the `session` scope in Spring.
- `session` may refer to `HttpSession` as speciffied by the [Servlet API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). This is not really related to Spring, even if you can use the standard `HttpSession` from within Spring, is more in general related to the Servlet API.

In Spring Security:

- If you are talking of Spring Security, instead of `session` I would talk of `SecurityContext`. The `SecurityContext` is actually stored as an `HttpSession` and restored to the `SecurityContextHolder` at every request. Here is were all security-related infos are stored for the current session. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#session-mgmt) for more details. In general a `SecurityContext` (at least at a very basic level) exists from the moment you login to the moment you logout. Because it is stored as an `HttpSession` it expires when the `HttpSession` expires (again, see the Servlet API specifications for more details)

Luca

Comment: Does it always expire when HttpSession  expires?

Comment: Yes, because it is stored within it